# Add image source in Jquery

Tags: jquery

In my MVC app, the images will b in the App_Data folder. I want to give the source to my img tag in Jquery. Here is how I do it:

```
var src1 = <%=Url.Content(Server.MapPath("/AppData/1.jpg"))%>
$("#imgLocation").attr("src", src1);
```

But it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try following:

```
var src1 = '<%=Url.Content(Server.MapPath("~/AppData/1.jpg"))%>';
$("#imgLocation").attr("src", src1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are trying do access an HTML element which is called `imgLocation` 
You either have to use

1. `$('#imgLocation')` if your img has an **ID** of `id="imgLocation"`
2. or `$('.imgLocation')` if your img has a **class** of `class="imgLocation"`

Comment: is the img already on your page when you execute that script ? is it placed within document ready ? provide more code or more details please !

Comment: have you tried to set the src="" in your img to something default like img id="img Location" src="spacer.gif" and then overwrite it with your javascript ?

Comment: I tried src="1.jpg" and I put the 1.jpg image in the same folder as the view, but it says that 1.jpg isn't found.

Comment: is your javascript code placed within your view, or is it placed somewhere else ? you should probably check if your 1.jpg is really placed within the directory where the javascript is being placed.,

Comment: Yes it is in the same folder.

Comment: this is your root directory. so is the 1.jpg in the same directory where the javascript is in ?

Comment: Yes it is. The JS is in the view, and the 1.jpg is also in the view.